# How to make requests not match in load testing?

Tags: performance, testing, python-requests, jmeter, loadrunner

First of all I apologize for my bad English, I'll try to be clear.
I tried to run a Test in jmeter with 60 threads with 600 seconds for Ramp-up during for example: 15 minutes. The problem is that as I understand jmeter should distribute the load in at most 1 hits per second, which is not happening.

I'm using a Constant Throughput Timer with "Calculate Throughput based on (this thread only)" on 1 sample per minute. When the minute passes, the requests begin to coincide up to 10 hits per second.
I understand that this happens because the first thread executes a request and when the minute passes another thread executes a request and so on until the ramp up time is over.

The question is: is there any way to limit the hits per second, achieving, for example, in a test of 180 requests per minute, the hits per second reach a maximum of 3? exactly distributing the load evenly?

I hope I was clear

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you're using:

1. Not very accurate timer
2. The timer is not properly configured, it limits the number of request per minute for 1 thread and not considering other threads. Due to concurrency you can have > than one hit per second, you need to switch to `all active threads (shared)`

It will be much easier to use either [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer), they are more accurate and self-explanatory.